# windows forms programming methodology for web apps

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications

I am used to windows form apps in C#. Is there some way I can design and develop web apps like win forms ?? I mean designing the ui like drag and drop ? I have a dll of .net version 2.0 and I want to use it with C#, for backend and web ui for front end(Im not a ui developer at all. I am from python background and recently started with C#)

Please suggest in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run Visual Studio and create an ASP.NET Web Application (you can use Web Forms template to have a working sample ready to use).